# Emacs VS Sublime Text 2 (on PC)

Tags: emacs, ide

I'm struggling to find a VS between emacs and sublime text.

The only difference I've found is it's easier to use sublime text. I don't care about easiness but efficiency. I've watched a bunch of emacs video and it seemed really efficient, played a bit with it but didn't really dig into it as I found a lot of people talking about sublime text.

Also I'm on windows, is emacs the same as on ubuntu or is it limited in some sort?

I'm thinking about programming in c++ with it. (I've also seen people using emacs to browse/post on HN, how do they do that??).

Thank-you!

EDIT :

Since this topic was closed (unrightfully) and still brings questions, here's my answer :

- Emacs doesn't work well on windows.
- Sublime Text 2 works on linux, mac, windows perfectly
- Sublime Text 2 has a packet manager, very easy to install plugins
- Sublime Text 2 is awesome and easy to learn. See the free tutorial on tutsplus.
- Ditch Emacs.

Comment: On Windows you can either use the native NTEmacs, or install Cygwin and use its Emacs package. You may still want Cygwin to provide external tools (find, grep, etc) even if you use NTEmacs, although Cygwin is not the only option. You should do some reading about all this. As for your last question, keep in mind that Emacs runs its own programming language (Emacs Lisp), and therefore there is not a lot that it can't do.